# Configure pip comand line arguments

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, pip

I have to configure pip command line arguments during deploying an app on AppEngine, like:
`pip install requirements.txt -i host.com --version x.x` etc

Is it possible?

Comment: Have you seen this article - https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/using-libraries-python-27 - about installing 3rd party pure Python libraries for using in your GAE app? Or does this not cover the full functionality? Explain in more detail please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you're using the new Python 3.7 runtime, which allows you to deploy by specifying a `requirements.txt` file.

Any arguments that you can pass to the `pip install` command can be included in your `requirements.txt` file per-dependency (see [the Requirements File Format](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#requirements-file-format)).

So if you currently have a `requirements.txt` like:

```
foo==1.2.3
bar==0.0.1
```

You can update this to be:

```
foo==1.2.3 -i host.com
bar==0.0.1 -i host.com
```

And then these arguments will be used when installing those dependencies.

(As an aside, I'm not sure what you're trying to do with the `--version` flag in your example, it won't have any effect on `pip install` command.)